# Capture text with pywinauto

Tags: python, windows, automation, pywinauto

I am trying to use pywinauto in Python to capture data from an application. I manage to track down the window I am interested in, but can't seem to access any text within that window.

1. Instance: `print(win)`:

   ```
   hwndwrapper.HwndWrapper - '', Folio Document
   ```
2. Properties: `print(win.get_properties())`:

   ```
   {'class_name': 'Folio Document', 
    'friendly_class_name': 'Folio Document', 
    'texts': [''], 
    'control_id': 0, 
    'rectangle': <RECT L142, T161, R765, B742>, 
    'is_visible': True, 
    'is_enabled': True, 
    'control_count': 0, 'style': 1342177280, 
    'exstyle': 0, 
    'user_data': 0, 
    'context_help_id': 0, 
    'fonts': [<LOGFONTW 'MS Shell Dlg' -11>], 
    'client_rects': [<RECT L0, T0, R623, B581>], 
    'is_unicode': False, 'menu_items': [], 
    'automation_id': ''}
   ```
3. Output from inspect.exe:
   [image]

The application I am interested in is called Folio Views. I want to copy the text from a book I own to a text file in order to use it in linux:

[image]

The text is selectable as shown above, but not copyable. I also cannot find a way to "see" this text with pywinauto.

How can I find the text within the application?

Comment: I had no chance to try it with the app. But one possible workaround is `.type_keys("^a^c")` and then get data using module `pywinauto.clipboard`.

Comment: @VasilyRyabov That is a clever solution (will keep in mind for other projects)! Unfortunately the text is not copyable - right-click has no copy option and ctrl-c is ineffective.

Comment: Well, I've requested a demo version. What I can see now: you're using `backend="win32"` which is default for `Application()` object. Try `Application(backend="uia")` and method `app.ApproximateMainWindowTitle.dump_tree()`. This output would be useful as well as `Inspect.exe` screenshot.

Comment: @VasilyRyabov I've added inspect.exe output to the question and the dump_tree with "uia" backend returns the following relevant child at the same inspect.exe position:  Pane - ''    (L304, T110, R1134, B765) ['', 'Pane2', '0', '1']

Comment: Hmm... It looks like there are no text and no children available for this control. You may try to switch to "UI Automation" mode (MSAA is old automation technology). But it's a high probability we're out of luck here. It seems Folio Views has a defense against text copying.

Comment: And the demo has not been arrived yet. Not a good technical support. One week delay already.

Comment: @VasilyRyabov thats all right, thanks for the extra mile. I've come to the conclusion that the text just isn't accessible via tools other than elaborate OCR techniques. (I have tried pytesseract for OCR, but the output is too unreliable). The text is not that important too me, I initially thought it would be an easy task.